# Send drive file to python telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to get my telegram bot to download a pdf document that is on google drive, but I can't get it to work.
I made the following code to be able to get it to work but there was no case in this:

`url = bot.get_File(link='link of google drive') down = url.download() bot.sendDocument(chat_id=ChatId, document=open(down,'rb'), filename="Lista de precios.pdf")`

I don't put the google drive link for privacy reasons, but obviously it would go there.
I don't know if it is possible to download a file from drive just like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong method, `get_file` is used to [download](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.get_file) a file from Telegram.
When sending a file via Telegram bot you can use the full URL **if this points to a file** (ie file.pdf)

```
bot.send_document(chat_id=Chat_id, document='https://github.com/user/project/raw/master/data/pdf/07-03-2020.pdf'
```

In case of Google Drive you have a URL that streams the file so you need to **1)** download and save the file locally **2)** open the local file and send it as file type

```
r = requests.get('googleDriveUrl', allow_redirects=True)
open('file.ppt', 'wb').write(r.content)

bot.send_document(chat_id=Chat_id, document=open('file.ppt', 'rb'), filename="file.pptx")
```